# Check a variable in python

Tags: python

I have a double variable in python **performance** that i want to check whether is empty or not. Is the following code do the job?

```
if re.match("^\d?\.\d+?$", performance) is None:
```

Is that code checking whether the variable is empty or not?

Comment: What do you think that line of code is doing?

Comment: If your variable is a double, checking it with a regular expression won't even run (`re`s apply to strings...)

Comment: this `^\d?\.\d+?$` expects not just empty/non-empty entry, but digits

Comment: I know what re.match does but not what this thing performs: ^\d?\.\d+?$

Comment: What is the type of `performance`? If it's a double, it has no concept of being "empty". If it's a string, just test `if performance:` because empty strings evaluate to `False`. If it's either a double or `None`, use `if performance is None:`.

Comment: So it is just checking whether or not there is some digits in my variable?

Comment: performance needs to be double and i want to check if the values are numbers and not empty or string.

Comment: There are websites for explaining regexes. https://regex101.com/r/Iix2fd/1. Also, you don't need `is None`.

Comment: Actually the variable is a string, but i want to check if it is correspond to a double number.

Comment: Regex are slow. The pythonic way is to use exceptions as I suggest in my answer below (https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=eafp#term-eafp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to check if the values are numbers and not empty or string

The right regex pattern would look as below:

```
performance = '.03'
if re.search(r'^(\d*\.)?\d+$', performance):
    print(performance, 'is a digit')
```

Comment: Actually the variable is a string, but i want to check if it is correspond to a double number.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is empty (NoneType) then it is not a float. So to check if it is a valid floating point number you don't really need to check for a digits you just do:

```
if type(performance) == 'float':
    # do stuff
```

or if the performance is a string to be checked if it's valid double:

```
try:
    float(performance)
except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
    print 'Not a float', str(e)
```

Comment: Actually the variable is a string, but i want to check if it is correspond to a double number.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one to check if performance is float (and int):

```
if performance != None and performance.lstrip("-+").replace(".","",1).isdigit():
```